# Iptables redirect HTTP traffic to proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, http, redirect

I have a local HTTP proxy running, if I configure my browser to go through it works perfectly but I would need to leave the browser configuration blank and only redirect the traffic to the proxy with iptables (or any other mechanism).

I tried these rules (separately) without succeeding (proxy returns 400 bad request error):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:8082
```

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8082`

Is it even possible to use an HTTP proxy with only iptables ? Or does the HTTP request has to be rewritten as well ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is called "transparent proxy". You need two things to do it:

1. Your proxy server should support it (transparent proxy). [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a well-known proxy server which supports transparent proxy mode.
2. Configure your firewall / router to redirect HTTP traffic to your proxy like the iptables rule you have.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I don't think my proxy supports transparent mode (I am using a c++ library called fhscanhttplibrary). Therefore it's impossible to do that with a regular proxy I guess ? In the end I would like to have two proxies encapsulating the HTTP traffic inside a file for instance (client <-> client proxy <->server proxy <-> web server), but I'm not really sure how to make the proxy chaining. I tried to run two HTTP proxies but the second one refuses the connection from the first one.